# centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:) not called

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

In a `CoreBluetooth` related iOS app written in Swift (4.2), I have the following problem.

The app handles a certain number of `Peripherals` and `Centrals`.
Each `Peripheral` provides a service and has several `Centrals` connected to it; it keeps an accounting of that and knows how many Centrals are connected.

In the same way each `Central` is connected to several `Peripherals`; and also keeps an accounting of that to know how many `Peripherals` are connected.

The question I have is about the book-keeping to maintain the accounting I was just mentioning, up to date.

From the `Peripheral` side, it works and I can see when a `Central` has disconnected.
For that I use:
    *peripheralManager(_:central:didSubscribeTo:)*
and:
    *peripheralManager(_:central:didUnsubscribeFrom:)*

From the `Central` I want to use:
    *centralManager(_:didConnect:)*
and:
    *centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)*

But here, for some reason, it does not work. The first function (*centralManager(_:didConnect:)*) is called as expected but not the second (*centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)*).

I suppose this last issue of the function not being called is what I need to solve. But I may be wrong.

As a result, I see when a `Peripheral` is coming but not when it is leaving.

What am I missing? Or am I just doing it wrong?

I test the app using two devices.

--- Further information --- (Post update)

Here is some of the related code:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
                    didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                    advertisementData: [String : Any],
                    rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print(#function)

    if cbPerifList  == nil {cbPerifList = [CBPeripheral]()}

    if let perifIndx = cbPerifList!.index(where:{$0.identifier==peripheral.identifier}) {
        central.connect(cbPerifList[perifIndx], options: nil)
    } else {
        peripheral.delegate = self
        cbPerifList.append(peripheral)
        central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }
}
```

One more possibly relevant thing I noticed is the following. Instead of switching of the peripheral by a button switch as I should normally do, I force kill the app on the device currently playing the peripheral role, then the *centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)* function is called on the other device as I would expect it to be; and the accounting is correctly performed.

Comment: You are doing it wrong, but you haven't shown any code, so we can't say what. You should edit your question to show the relevant code from your central side.

Comment: If I haven't shown any code, it is because I was not sure about the relevant code.
Obviously showing the code for "centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)" which was not called, was not going to help. I have added a piece of code, you can let me know if you want a different piece. And below the code I have also added some new information which may well give you a hint, though I am not sure.

Comment: From your additional note it seems like the problem is with how you are “disconnecting” from the peripheral. Can you show that code?

Comment: please provide your code for `didDisconnectPeripheral` incase the error is there.

Comment: The error cannot be there because it is not called.

Comment: @Paulw11. OK. I will have to perform some "house-keeping" in the code to properly show the relevant part(s). But I can already see that I am probably not doing what I should do to have the "centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)" function fire on the other side. Is there some specific function call I need to make when switching of one peripheral?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to disconnect from the peripheral side, aside from probably releasing your `CBPeripheralManager` entirely.  Disconnection will occur when the peripheral goes out of range (or you turn Bluetooth off, terminate the app etc)

Comment: Oh! I see, that is bad news. So that means there is not way to do what I want. The central will keep believing in the existence of a given peripheral "for ever", though it may have been switched off.

Comment: Well, you can't switch it off; you can only stop advertising it.  This will prevent new centrals from discovering it, but the connection state is effectively managed by the central

Comment: I understand I have ended up by using a different approach to get the result I want for the user.

Comment: @Paulw11 centralManager has `cancelPeripheralConnection(CBPeripheral)`

Comment: Yes, you can cancel the connection from the central side, but not from the peripheral side

Answer (score 1):

In my `CoreBluetooth` App

```
func centralManager (_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
}
```

Is called when ever peripheral is lost.

Maybe check your syntax of your `didDisconnectPeripheral` func.

Comment: I am never calling this cancelPeripheralConnection function, could that be the very problem? I need to check.

Comment: I have a question: where do you call the cancelPeripheralConnection function?

Comment: After reading about this cancelPeripheralConnection function that you mention.
I do not have the impression this is going to do me any good in the current situation.

It is used by the central manager to cancel a connection to a peripheral and this is not what I need. I want to know (from the central manager perspective), that a peripheral has gone away (independently of me).

Comment: Yes I understand. I stated that the method will be called whether I force the disconnection OR if the peripheral is lost (connection, powers off, etc) @Michel

Comment: Exactly, I had to use another approach.

Comment: @Michel it's great you found a work-around solution. But your logic of "The error cannot be there because it is not called." seems flawed. Maybe it's not called because you have the incorrect handler. I see now post-edit, that `didDisconnectPeripheral` is called when force-quit app but not when button-quit peripheral, correct? Also maybe you could post your 'other approach' as an answer.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and posted my 'other approach'. Beside I do not agree on you comment about "The error cannot be there because it is not called." The fact it is called when force-quit app but not when button-quit peripheral is true, but that shows something about the conditions making the call happen or not, which is something external to the function. As long as execution does not reach inside the function, however good or bad it is will have no influence on the world.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a direct answer to this question.
Reading the comments seems to show there is now answer. In other words what I wanted to do sounds impossible. If some expert happens to know otherwise, please let us know.

In the meanwhile I made a work-around solution:

When shutting of one peripheral, I use one of its characteristics to set some non-sense value which is then used as hint by the central to know that the peripheral has "said good-bye"..... And it works.